# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'LeistungGruppe' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to add an EntityObject to my database by calling AddToLeistungGruppe.

LeistungGruppe in this case is my Table with Primary_Key LeistungGruppe_ID with Identity true and Identity increment 1 and seed 1.

I search a lot for this issue and alot of People got he same error.
They were told to simply set StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity and this would solve the Problem.

I tried it out and still got the same issue. 
I'm new to the Entity Framework and have no idea about how to solve this Problem.

Somehow i think the model isn't updated probably because even if i Switch around These Settings I'm getting the same error over and over again.

Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to save an object to the database with an explicit ID set by you while the database is expecting to generate that value itself. That is the LeistungGruppe_ID property in your object is set to something other than 0 and it is not identified to the EF framework as an identity field.  If you want the Id to be generated by the database as your post suggests, then the corresponding property in the Object should be decorated with the [Key] attribute.

If you are using the Fluent API then you should have something like this in your DBContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<LeistungGruppe>().Property(x => x.LeistungGruppe_ID).StoreGeneratedPattern = StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity;
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```